# How to specify that cover art for a video in iTunes should be a frame from a specific time in the video?

Tags: itunes, video, defaults, movie

When I add a movie or other video to iTunes, it appears that iTunes selects a video frame from somewhere near the beginning of the video file as the **default cover art** — and most of the time this is a terrible choice.

Many of the shows and movies in my collection have an opening sequence containing frames where a title is plainly shown (e.g. *"Dr. Seuss' How the Grinch Stole Christmas!"*), or at least there's some scene in the video which is distinct & identifiable, a scene I would clearly recognize when scrolling through my collection with the Cover Flow view.

I'd like to specify such a distinct frame, from an arbitrary point in a video, as a video's cover art.  I expected a slider somewhere to seek through a video and find just the right spot to use as cover, but I didn't find such functionality.

1. How does iTunes determine which frame to select for the cover art from a video?
2. Is there a way to tell iTunes to **use a different video frame** as the cover art?
3. Failing that, what is a good alternative?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The frame that's used is called the "Poster Frame". It looks like iTunes chooses a frame 10 seconds into the video by default.

To choose a specific frame as the cover art:

1. Start playing the video.
2. Pause the video on the frame you want to use.
3. Right-click on the video and choose "Set Poster Frame".

Comment: Thanks!  I knew it was hiding somewhere :-)  I was expecting to see the feature under the Get Info... Artwork tab, but I didn't think to actually play the video to look for this.  Also good to know what this is officially called - thanks again.